# Spark on EC2 cannot utilize all cores available

Tags: amazon-ec2, mapreduce, apache-spark

I am running [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) on a EC2 cluster set up via [spark-ec2.sh](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/ec2-scripts.html) script. The 5 slave instances I launched have 40 cores intotal, but each instance just cannot utilize all the cores.

From the slave log, I can see it seems slaves execute tasks one by one. And I ran top on slave instances, the cpu is around 100% instead of 800%.

I have turned on the spark.mesos.coarse mode. And the data is splited into 40 chunks. And it can utilize 8 cores when I run Spark in stand alone mode on my local.

Is there anything I can do to make the Spark slaves to utilize all the cores available?

Comment: `spark.mesos.coarse` only affects Spark when running under Mesos.  Are you running Spark under Mesos or with Spark's Standalone Mode (if you're using Spark 0.7+, the default EC2 script uses Standalone mode).

Comment: Thanks @JoshRosen, for you timely reply. I was using 0.7, so it should be Standalone mode. I want to use Spark for real time query with the response time within 1 ~ 2 seconds. Is it possible?

Comment: Spark is definitely capable of low-latency queries; this is the basis of Shark and Spark Streaming.  The underutilization could be due to your job not having enough parallelism or due to locality constraints.  Could you provide some more details about your job?  Also, consider posting this question on the [spark-users](http://groups.google.com/group/spark-users) mailing list.  That list is better suited to back-and-forth debugging discussions than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `spark.cores.max` let's say to `8` before creating `SparkContext`

in Spark 0.9:

```
val conf = new SparkConf() 
   .setMaster("...")
   .set("spark.cores.max", "8")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Comment: From top command I can see multiple cores are engaged. The problem is that it seems the cpu takes a while to be fully engaged to the task. My realtime query takes about 3~4 seconds, but it seems the ec2 virtualization won't grant all the cpu power to the process immidiately.

Comment: I don't have a physical cluster to use, so, no. But when I did on my local computer, CPU utilization goes to 100% immediately